# RxJava: Chain asynchronous callback-style webservices

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have some data that is continuously emitted from a hardware device. This data needs first to be sent continuously to webservice A that returns a stream of results after some time if enough data has arrived. Then each result has to be forwarded as soon as it arrives to webservice B which in turn returns a stream of different results after some time if enough results from A have arrived. Each webservice has an asynchronous callback-style API. Also some connection setup is needed before data is sent for the first time to each webservice.

How can I map this to RxJava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` and `concatMap` are the main tools for asynchronous chaining.

You need to wrap your webservices into `Future`s. And your hardware device into `Observable` source. Then it is as easy as:

```
class WebServices {
    Future<Response1> callService1(parameters) { ... }
    Future<Response2> callService2(parameters) { ... }
}

hardwareSource
    .flatMap(v -> Observable.fromFuture(callService1(...)))
    .flatMap(r1 -> Observable.fromFuture(callService2(...)))
    .subscribe(r2 -> System.out.println(r2));
```

In case webservices receive and send *series* of messages they should be wrapped into `Observable`s. And processing pipeline would look like:

```
class WebServices {
    Observable<Response1> sendToService1(parameters) { ... }
    Observable<Response2> sendToService2(parameters) { ... }
}

hardwareSource
    .flatMap(v -> sendToService1(...))
    .flatMap(r1 -> sendToService2(...))
    .subscribe(r2 -> System.out.println(r2));
```

And in case incoming and outgoing streams for webservices do not strictly correlate (responses are not directly associated with requests) then I would implement those services as classes exposing both `Observer` and `Observable` interfaces.

```
// wire them up
hardwareSource.getObservable()
    .subscribe(webService1.getObserver());
webService1.getObservable()
    .subscribe(webService2.getObserver());
webService2.getObservable()
    .subscribe(resultHandler);

// initiate connections
webService2.connect()
webService1.connect()
hardwareSource.connect()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with `Future<Response1>` is that there's no single response to wait for. It's a stream of responses (0..n) and the amount of responses is not known beforehand. Additionally the results should be forwarded as soon as they arrive, hence even using a `Future<List<Response1>>` wouldn't help.

Comment: @aha OK. It looks even more reactive. You need to implement `Observable`s for each webservice then, and `flatMap` them directly. How do you get multiple responses from the same service? Do you make several http requests?

Comment: There's no direct correlation between the number of requests I make and the number of responses I receive. One service communicates over WebSockets, another one uses gRPC which means I've to setup the communication channels once beforehand and then stream.